# EF 6 Update-Database failed with provider

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm switching from a MySql database to a Sql Server database.

I remove all related data to mysql from configuration and web.config.

But I still get this issue on Update-Database command in Package manager console:

```
Update-Database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'B2Peer.Web'.
Using NuGet project 'B2Peer.EntityFramework'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the 
target database.
Target database is: 'b2peer' (DataSource: .\SQLLOCAL, Provider: 
System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending explicit migrations.
System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. 
Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

I cleaned the solution and rebuild

Is there any cache files that I can clean to avoid EF to look for a provider Mysql ?

Note: I searched with notepad++ in all files in my solution folder and there are nothing related to my search 'mysql' ... So why EF still looking for this provider ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally It was fixed.

After multiple clean, build, launch website with automatic migration to true.

Then Update-Database has stopped to give this error...